# How to implement Phonestatelistener in an activity

Tags: android

I have certain data which I got, when user fill a form in an activity. There is an option Mode where user can select RING or VIBRATE.

So my question is how could I actually implement it in my activity, I see various examples on Telephony manager and phonestatelistener

https://web.archive.org/web/20130424063712/http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/62.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

but it's hard to implement it in my application, I have data in text form only and don't know how to use this data to switch it from one mode to another. Please tell me in terms of coding examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phone state listener doesnt determine the ring or vibrate mode - it is for the call status (idle, ring, offhook)

to get the ring/vibrate/silent stau use Audiomanager

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.getRingerMode();// returns AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE or AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT or AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
// to set ringer mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```